# What country is related to a phenomenon which is related to Cronus?

Tags: greek

We were given this puzzle in class and i have no idea, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cronus (Saturn) and Jupiter merge, causing the Bethlehem star phenomenon.
That said, Bethlehem is in Palestine.
This is probably the answer.

https://earthsky.org/human-world/was-the-christmas-star-real

Comment: Unlikely - the Nazarene's birthday in December was set by clergy centuries after the verses that mention a star were written. This was done to associate Christianity with the much older pagan tradition of Saturnalia.

Comment: @Codosaur Nevertheless, we are talking about legend, not historicity.

Comment: Italy, particularly Rome. Romans worshipped Saturn/Chronus. Saturnalia was the Roman feast that became the Christmas phenomenon. Hope OP returns with the answer!

Comment: You are a genius, my teacher almost got a heart attack from the thought someone could solve it